# How to fill authentication challenge for the user with a default value?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I have a html page that asks the user for a username and a password through an authentication challenge window. What I need to do is to enter a default value for the username and password by myself using Javascript or whatever so that the user can access the page without typing the username and the password.

In other words, In order to access the page you have to enter a username and a password through authentication challenge window. What I do now is to alert a message that tells the user enter "guest" for the username and "guest" for the password so that he can access the page. But I don't want this to happen. I want to handle the authentication challenge by my self by setting the username and password so that the user won't have to enter them.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the app alerts the user with the credentials to use, why have authentication at all?

Comment: Do you have any code examples?

Comment: Is there a code sample you can post that demonstrates what have you tried so far? http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx

Comment: No kidding... with a bit of HTML I'm thinking the solution could be quite simple!

Comment: @KevinBoucher It needs to work this way for my app to work as I want

Comment: @KevinBoucher I would assume that this has already been thought through by the OP and so he has a need regardless.

Comment: You know what happens when we assume.

Comment: @Jimmmy I need something to work with any html page that I need to handle its authentication challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a value attribute to a text box using:

```
    <input id="mytextbox" type="text" value="FOOBAR" />
    <input id="myPassWord" type="password" value="SOMEVAL" />
```

KevinBoucher does have a point about security, though I'm assuming you've thought it through.

Other solutions would be to use JavaScript to reference the above by ID

```
    document.getElementById("mytextbox").value = "FOOBAR";
```

Without examples it's hard to come up with a solid solution though :)

Comment: I don't have element to get. I need to fill an authentication challenge not a form.

Comment: This is why we need an example. You may not be wanting to use JavaScript or HTML at all, but perhaps VBA and Excel... or who knows what else. If this is a pop up type authentication challenge then .... good grief! EXAMPLE :)